# Discrete probability distribution with a given maximum

Tags: probability

I have to generate a random discrete probability distribution of `n` elements with a given maximum value.

I know how to create a classic one but I have no clues how to generate a random discrete probability distribution of `n` elements who respect `max(distribution) = p`. By that I mean that the highest probability of the distribution must be `p in [0;1[`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Let `random` function returns values in interval [0; 1]. You can use a formula `values[i] = expectedValue + 2 * p * (random() - 1);`

Comment: What do you mean by max(distribution) = p? With discrete probability distributions you have two sets of numbers -- the numbers that occur (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6 when rolling a die) and the probability of those numbers occurring (e.g. the number 1/6). It is unclear what you intend.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko What is `expectedValue`in your comment ? And is `p`really in the distribution ?

Comment: @JohnColeman by `max(distribution)=p` I mean that the highest probability in the distribution must be equal to `p in [0;1[`

Comment: @elnabo -- that is of course trivial (let p(0) = p, pick n large enough so that (1-p)/(n-1) < p, and assign the probability (1-p)/(n-1) to the elements 2,3,...,n.) Since you probably are not looking for an answer like that I suspect that there are some constraints you are not specifying.

Comment: @JohnColeman Indeed I forgot to specify that I wanted the other elements to have random probability but inferior to p. Gonna edit question.

Comment: @elnabo -- do you have any restrictions on the number of elements in the distribution?

Comment: @JohnColeman No, as long as it possible to respect the maximum probability constraint. So not 2 elements with p < 0.5

Comment: You're not calculating [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution) in you pseudo code. You normalize a set of random data.

Comment: You can't demand only `max` of distribution. There are endless options about how the curve behaves going to the sides. For example you can have a triangle by summing up two independent random values with even distribution. Summing up 3 values will give a Gaussian-like bell. [ref](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf). If you don't care about the form of distribution you can configure `p` with coefficients and achieve a triangle summing up to indepenant randoms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hit and miss approach (often used in probability simulations to randomly choose elements which satisfy certain constraints). The performance is acceptable *unless np is too close to 1*. Here is a Python implementation, which should be easy enough to translate to other languages:

```
from random import random

def makeDist(n,p):
    #assumes p*n > 1
    miss = True
    while miss:
        x = [p]
        rest = [random() for i in range(1,n)]
        total = sum(rest)
        rest = [x*(1-p)/total for x in rest]
        if all(x < p for x in rest):
            x.extend(rest)
            miss = False #we have a hit!
    return x
```

Typical output:

```
>>> dist = makeDist(6,0.2)
>>> dist
[0.2, 0.08986510724051082, 0.18690143846768711, 0.19758176720598397, 0.19299989610231708, 0.13265179098350102]
>>> max(dist)
0.2
>>> sum(dist)
1.0
>>> makeDist(3,0.35)
[0.35, 0.31154704906869274, 0.33845295093130723]
>>>
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood your comment about the constraint on the number of elements. The number of elements in the distribution is fixed to `n`.